# Is this sufficient to do when your PC is infected with a virus?

Tags: windows, reinstall

My PC was infected by belombrea. I was told to reinstall OS, but I did it a different way. Is this sufficient?

Go to the search bar, type reset, click reset this PC. It'll give 3 options. On the bottom there's more recovery options with "learn how to start fresh with a clean installation of Windows PC", is that the same as reinstalling the OS? If I try click, it'll tell me that I'll need to reinstall Dell Touchpad, Realtek Card Reader & Realtek High Definition Audio Driver from the web. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

According to many removal tutorials, removing Belombrea.com's adware doesn't require reinstalling Windows, but is possible either manually or using malware removal tools like Malwarebytes (no affiliation). The manual removal includes removing the package that installed Belombrea alongside (from `appwiz.cpl`) and removing its browser extensions.

It doesn't seem like Belombrea is trying to hide anywhere deeper than that, but in general full recovery after a malware infection may require reinstallation, preferably from a media that couldn't have been tampered by the malware. From that perspective, using recovery partitions was a very bad idea compared to optical installation media provided before.